# Eureka TextRow layout problems

Tags: swift, uikit, eureka-forms

I'm trying to configure a TextRow to have:

- subtitle cellStyle
- multiline text label

Sample:

```
 let textRow = TextRow() {
      $0.tag = "TextRow"
      $0.cellStyle = .subtitle
      $0.title = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,"
      $0.cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    }
```

But, as you can see, the layout is not correct; any help? Thanks

[image: layout problem]

Sample source code [here](https://github.com/brunofrani/MultilineTextRow)

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems fixed now after this [pull request](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka/issues/2058)